# VLAN turns up in UI, not API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I go to `Network -> IP Management -> VLANS` I see three `VLANs` listed.

When I call `getPublicNetworkVlans` and `getPrivateNetworkVlans` via the API on the account, I only see two.

The missing `VLAN` is the direct link for the cross connect to our enterprise. What API should I call to be able to see this missing one from my code?

Comment: Sounds more like a support question.

Answer (score 2):

The [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com/) works with [SoftLayer_Account::getNetworkVlans](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans) method, you should be able to see the vlan with it.

Let me know your results, for further investigation if you are not able to retrieve the vlan.

Comment: That was it. getNetworkVlans returns it whereas neither getPublicNetworkVlans or getPrivateNetworkVlans does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue would be language specific but can you provide the code you are using to retrieve the VLAN's? My guess is that the cross connect is a special VLAN that is not exposed in the same manner as regular VLANs.